# Relieves allegiance

Tags: collocations

Let's say you are in a pact of allegiance to a country. Then, you 'stop' or 'cancelled' it for an unknown reason.

> 'Your country **relieves allegiance** to xxx country.'

Does this collocate well?

Comment: I suspect you mean *alliance*, not *allegiance*. In any case, *relieve* is not used to mean *withdraw from* or *revoke*.

Comment: Oh yeah, I thought allegiance and alliance are the same, hehe, well my bad. But in terms of 'allegiance' itself, can you still say 'relieves allegiance'?

Comment: As StoneyB says, no, you can't, not to mean *withdraw* or *revoke* allegiance to a country. You would use *withdraw* or *revoke*.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, [**allegiance**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/allegiance) is the loyalty that a citizen has to his or her country; it's not a relationship between countries.

Formally, you can [**forswear**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forswear) your allegiance, which is the opposite of **swearing** allegiance in the first place. Less formally, you can **revoke** or **renounce** your allegiance, although these verbs are more often applied to the noun **citizenship**.  If you commit a crime of treason, you have **betrayed** your allegiance.

Between nations as equal partners, there can be an [**alliance**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alliance). Both nations may agree to peacefully **dissolve** an alliance or one partner may peacefully **withdraw** from it.  Less peacefully, a partner to an alliance might **break** or **violate** the alliance.  Alliances are also said to **break down** when all parties disagree with each other.

If two nations are formally in an alliance, but one nation is obviously much weaker and being dominated or propped up by the stronger one, then the weaker one can be called a **client state** or even a **puppet state** (the latter term says that the weak government is probably not legitimate in some way) and the stronger is the **sponsor**.  A client state might **break away from** or **rebel against** its sponsor; a sponsor might **abandon** its client.